# Как сделать форк наследуемых зависимостей в Composer

Tags: php, github, composer

У меня есть проект на laravel. К нему, через composer, подключена библиотека https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary. Она как зависимость тянет https://github.com/thephpleague/glide.

Одна из возможностей библиотеки - редактирование изображения (поворот, отражение, обрезка и т.п). Суть проблемы в том, что в glide нарушен порядок применяемых к изображению модификаторов (отражение картинки используется в последнюю очередь):

https://github.com/thephpleague/glide/pull/228

И я не понимаю, что делать. Pull request не принимается 10 дней (может быть он оформлен плохо, но с английским беда).

Если бы это была прямая зависимость - можно было бы создать свой форк и тянуть оттуда, иногда проверяя обновления и надеяться, что проблему решат и можно будет вернуться к библиотеке. Но когда зависимость не прямая - это превращается в какое-то извращение.

Вопрос в том, что делать в подобной ситуации?

Answer (score 1):

1. Склонировать два упомянутых пакета в приватные репозитории или форкнуть их на гитхабе.
2. Сделать нужные фиксы в коде пакета `thephpleague/glide`, закомитить правки (лучше в отдельную ветку, например - `hotfix`).
3. Править `composer.json` у пакета `spatie/laravel-medialibrary`. Добавить в него VCS-репозиторий со ссылкой на `thephpleague/glide`, закомитить правки (лучше в отдельную ветку, например - `hotfix`).

**composer.json:**

```
"require": {
        "thephpleague/glide": "dev-hotfix"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://example.com/thephpleague/glide"
        }
    ]
```

4. Править `composer.json` у вашего проекта - добавить в него VCS-репозиторий со ссылкой на `spatie/laravel-medialibrary`.

**composer.json:**

```
"require": {
        "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "dev-hotfix"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://example.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary"
        }
    ]
```

5. Выполнить `composer update` для вашего проекта

В примерах показано использование веток `hotfix` в склонированных приватных репозиториях.