# Как правильно произвести изменения в пакете, установленном через composer (Magento 2)?

Tags: composer, magento

В пакете в одном файле нужно внести правки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думаю, что просто править здесь - не лучший вариант, ведь при обновлении пакета, правки затрутся (хотя пакет уже несколько лет и не обновляется).

Подскажите, какова практика оверрайдинга пакетов (в контексте Magento 2)?

Comment: Общая практика такая - форкаете нужный пакет для правок. Клонируете его. Пушите измения. Подключаете в `composer.json` репозиторий с исправленным пакетом и устанавливаете его через `composer require ...` Посмотрите [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/953330/327441) ответ

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1226942/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b2-magento-2