# Как переопределить файл модуля в Magento 2?

Tags: magento

Вот в этом файле нужно произвести изменения:

```
/app/code/Mageants/Shopbylook/Controller/Shopbylook/Cart.php
```

Как правильно это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Плагин (Plugin) если надо манипулировать входными/выходными даными определенного метода класса либо Переопределение (Preference) если необходимо круто поменять логику какого-то метода.

[читать](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-use-plugin-preference-rewrite-block-model-controller-helper-magento-2.html)

[читать](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)

[читать](https://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-2-plugin-and-preference/)